# my custom vm.args is not getting copied

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place or something, but my vm.args file doesn't get in to the release. I just get the default one that it builds. You're supposed to put it in the ./rel directory, right? The same one that it puts your releases under?

Comment: Take a look at the last comment on this issue @Matt: https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/42

Comment: Also are you trying to use exrm on Windows Matt?  I know there are some issues with exrm on Windows but I don't think that's one of them.

Comment: Are you using a standard or umbrella project?

Comment: A standard project

Comment: Matt--probably need a few more details.Which version of exrm?  Which version of Elixir?  OS?  etc. (I mean assuming that this is still an issue for you :) )